# Does Leaflet always work in decimal degrees?

Tags: web-mapping, leaflet

I'm looking into [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/) and I'm surprised that it doesn't (seem to) specify coordinates in Web Mercator like other popular APIs, but instead uses decimal degrees.

Are all coordinates in Leaflet specified in decimal degrees? Is there a function to translate into other coordinate systems (as in the [geographicToWebMercator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/namespace_geometry.htm#webMercatorToGeographic) option in ArcGIS)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for other projektions in Leaflet is rather new, I think. You might read more about it in this blogpost from Kartena:

http://blog.kartena.se/local-projections-in-a-world-of-spherical-mercator/